# How to make gradle to read from "src" directory instead of "bin/test"

Tags: java, gradle

I am using gradle to build a java project and execute (in local machine using eclipse).

gradle always reads files from "bin" folder.
How to make it read from "src" folder ? Because I have a few html files which will be edited dynamically (for debugging) ? (without restarting the server)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case your folder containing your html files is declared as a resource folder, they should be copied next to your java build results. (default resource location is: src/main/resources) You could edit those dynamically.

In case this is not enough for your needs, a quick fix might be to create a symlink, provided your application is able to follow symlinks (I'd guess java handles it fine by default)

Another would be to adjust your application to set the resource location the html files are provided from, using a configuration file loaded by your application or even just a command line argument when executing your jar. (e.g. a development / production switch where resources are expected)

Answer (score 0):

By default, gradle will compile java files in `src/main/java` and will consider anything in `src/main/resources` as a resource (ie packed inside the jar and available on the runtime classpath). Unless you have good reason to do so, I suggest you stick to these very sensible, industry accepted conventions.

Gradle will (by default) use the "build" dir for task outputs (eg compiled classes, jar files etc). Gradle will NOT do anything with the "bin" directory (by default).

The "bin" directory is an Eclipse concept. Eclipse will compile classes to the "bin" directory and possibly copy resources there too. Anything to do with that directory is likely done by eclipse

Comment: The issue with mine is "Build Automatically" is not checked in my eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse will compile java files to "bin" directory and also copy resources to "bin" directory every time it builds. If you have "build automatically" unticked then your html files in the "bin" directory won't be up to date until the next build. You could add "src/main/resources" to your application's runtime classpath (ensuring its ordered first, before "bin" directory). Another option is to use the [FileSync](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/filesync#group-screenshots) plugin to automatically copy your resources to "bin" directory when they change